# How to replace parts of a line with search/replace in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, search, groovy

I am trying to find all cases of `println` and replace them with `log.debug()` for starters, then clean up the logs. Is there a tool somewhere than can help me do that? Is this even possible? We are trying to replace both the beginning of a line with `log.debug(` *AND* the end of it, with the `)`.

We are on:

```
Groovy 2.5.11
Java 1.8
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-202.6948.69
Windows OS
```

Example:

```
//find all instances of (text in logs is varied)
println "this is a log"

//and replace with
log.debug("this is a log")
```

Comment: Did you try Replace in Path feature with the regular expression group matching?

Comment: I have, but what that does is replace the pieces you are searching with/for. The hard part for me is to add the `)` at the very end because I don't want to replace the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Search pattern: `println "(.*?)"`
- Replace pattern: `log.debug("$1")`

[image: Replace in path]

Notice the regex search option is enabled (`.*` icon on the right).

[More details](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html#capture_groups_and_backreference) in IntelliJ IDEA documentation.

Comment: Absolutely amazing! This is perfect thank you so much. RegEx is a mystery to me.